# How to filter data on client side using firestore paging adapter?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am using `FirestorePagingAdapter` on a **Recycler View(GridLayoutManager)**. The issue I am facing is i need to exclude some items based on certain condition that are not possible through queries. Previously i could use the above code inside `onBindViewHolder` to hide them (LinearLayoutManager) but that's not working with GridLayoutManager. So i need some solution to either hide these item from Recycler View(GridLayoutManager) without consuming space or some way by which i remove those item before they are used by the adapter.

```java
if (/* some condition */) {
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams param = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams)
            holder.binding.getRoot().getLayoutParams();

    param.height = 0;

    param.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
}
```

Is there any callback/procedure available in `FirestorePagingAdapter` in which i can filter the data before the adapter uses it?

**Update:**

I have a Dishes Collection. I have local ArrayList of Allergies that i want to check against `dishAllergy` Field. It should skip the documents that contains any of the element of my local ArrayList Also i have another filter already applied on `dishCategory` Field too in the query too.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection(DISHES_COLLECTION).whereArrayContains(DISH_CATEGORY, category);
```

[image: Collection Document]

Comment: What is not possible with Query? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get/filter.

Comment: @AlexMamo i have added!

Comment: So you are looking for something like having whereArrayContains and whereNotIn method calls in the same query, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes. But i guess it's not possible in single query. Also a limit of 10 values.

Comment: @AlexMamo any solutions?